# export csv catch null value symfony 2

Tags: symfony, csv

I have some troubles with an export to csv. In my table I have some null value and I can't find out how to catch them.

```
public function exportCSVAction()
{
    $results = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()
        ->getRepository('MyRepoBundle:Cronexecution')->findAll();

    $response = new StreamedResponse();
    $response->setCallback(
        function () use ($results) {
            $handle = fopen('php://output', 'r+');
            foreach ($results as $row) {

                if (!($row->getNbLineIn()) && !($row->getNbLineOut())) {
                    $delContact = (($row->getNbLineIn()) - ($row->getNbLineOut()));
                }
                else{
                    $delContact="Unknown";
                }
                $data = array(
                    $row->getClient(),
                    $row->getDealingName(),
                    $row->$delContact,
                );
                fputcsv($handle, $data);
            }
            fclose($handle);
        }
    );
    $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/force-download');
    $response->headers->set('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="export.csv"');

    return $response;
}
```

When I delete the $row->$delContact the csv export work cause there isn't null value but when I let it I got a "This site can’t be reached" error.

So I tried to catch when it's null with 2 or 3 different method but impossible to figure it out.

Thanks for your help

Comment: $row->$delContact should be just $delContact but having said that, it is not clear to me what null value you are talking about.

Comment: some of my getNbLineOut() and getNbLineIn() are null so they just throw an error and don't want to create the csv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change according to bellow code :

```
$data = array(
         $row->getClient(),
         $row->getDealingName(),
         $delContact,
       );
```

Comment: Yeah thx a lot ! Now i try to figure how to put each in different row and not only in the "A" row with "," to separe them. But i think i have to do it in other format :/